# How does the inclusion map being an immersion imply it is smooth?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of a Lie group $G$. In Tu's book on manifolds he states

> ...being an immersion, the inclusion map $i: H \hookrightarrow G$ of a Lie subgroup $H$ is of course $C^\infty$.

This seems obvious, but I cannot see why the implication holds. Since $H$ is an immersed submanifold it may not have the same topology as $G$, so why should we expect continuity let alone smoothness?

Comment: What is the definition of immersion?

Comment: @JasonDeVito The differential is injective at every point.

Comment: Many authors only consider smooth maps, so define "Immersion" to be a smooth map with that condition on the differential.   Does Tu?  If not we clearly require some form of smoothness ($C^{1}?$) to talk about a differential - so is your question why, e.g., $C^{1}$ implies $C^{\infty}$ for Lie groups?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I checked and you are correct, Tu defines immersions to be $C^\infty$. Your question also got me thinking about the relationship between differentials and smoothness. I know differentials are motivated by derivatives on Euclidean space, and indeed in Tu differentials are defined to be $C^\infty$, but what is the link beyond this? Why is smoothness required to talk about differentials?

Comment: First, I almost never think about functions which are not $C^\infty$, so take this with a grain of salt.  One definition of the differential of a map is by taking a derivative of a composition:  $d_p f(v) = (f\circ \gamma)'(0)$ where $\gamma'(0) = v$.  This requires that $f\circ \gamma$ *has* a derivative.  Certainly if $f$ has a derivative at $\gamma(0)$, then this composition does as well, so let's assume that.  I don't know if you have to assume $C^1$ to get nice properties, maybe you do.  That said, once you get $C^1$ that is, in many senses, good enough:

Comment: There's a result of Whitney (and others?)  that if $M$ is a $C^1$-manifold  (in the sense of having an atlas of charts whose transitions are all $C^1$, then $M$ has a compatible $C^\infty$ atlas.  And, if $M$ and $N$ are $C^1$-diffeomorphic, then they are $C^\infty$-diffeomoprhic.  (I should also stress, both of these results are known to be false if we change $C^1$ to $C^0$.  That is, there are unsmoothable topological manifolds, and there are manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I see, so the simple reason is that we need smoothness (at least $C^1$) to even make the definitions work? For example, let $f: M \rightarrow N$ and $X$ a vector field on $M$. Then if we view the tangent vector $g \in T_{f(p)}N$ as derivation with a basis $\{\partial/\partial x_i\}$, then $f_*(X)(g) = X(g \circ f)$ requires $f$ to be at least $C^1$ in order to even apply $X$. Is this the right idea?